# Shifting mysql rows when you insert new row?

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

Lets say we have table something like top 100 and we are keeping this rank in table.let me be clear;

```
Singer|AlbumName|Rank(unique)
Eminem|xxxxxxxxx|1
Dr.Dre|×××××××××|2
50cent|xxxxxxxxx|3
..................
..................
Usher |xxxxxxxxx|99
Bieber|i'm b*tch|100
```

What im trying to do is when insert a new row how can i update their rank?Shifting all other row's rank?

```
Singer|AlbumName|Rank(unique)
Eminem|xxxxxxxxx|1
Sdog  |xxxxxxxxx|2
Dr.Dre|×××××××××|3
50cent|xxxxxxxxx|4
..................
Usher |xxxxxxxxx|100
```

To achieve this whats the logic? And what is the best practise?

Comment: Based on what you are giving the rank?

Comment: Yeap its based on entirely my willing

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution if anyone needs it later;

```
UPDATE `album` SET `rank`= rank + 1 WHERE rank >= $rankOfNewAlbum ORDER BY rank DESC
```

by doing this you start updating rows bacwards and there is no error because there is no matcing rank.

Then we can insert the new row.

Thanks for mario.klump for contribution and inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the rank of the new album, you can do an UPDATE before inserting the new album:

```
UPDATE album SET rank = rank + 1 where rank >= $rankOfNewAlbum
```

Comment: its not what im looking for but i suppose it can be modified with some php code then it works.Because in this version its giving an error because we are trying to update rank which already exist.Dr.Dre is second and we are trying to make it third but 50cent is third.I think we should start updating from end to $rankOfNewAlbum